# Undefined ao acessar atributos de classes em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, undefined

Boa tarde galera,
estava desenvolvendo uma api com node e mongo utilizando express e mongoose e tentei implementar o pattern repository, mas ao acessar os atributos de uma classe retorna uma mensagem de undefined que não sei o motivo, repliquei a mesma implementação em PHP e funcionou de boa.

Segue abaixo o código:

Model utilizando o mongoose

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const Pokemon = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: 'String',
    required: 'Name is required',
  },
  attack: {
    type: 'Number',
    required: 'Attack is required',
  },
  defense: {
    type: 'Number',
    required: 'Defense is required',
  },
  image: {
    type: 'String',
    required: 'Image is required',
  },
});
export default mongoose.model('Pokemon', Pokemon);
```

Repository do model

```
import BaseRepository from '../repositories/BaseRepository';
import Pokemon from '../models/Pokemon';

class PokemonRepository extends BaseRepository {
  constructor() {
    super(Pokemon);
  }
}

export default PokemonRepository;
```

Repository base

```
class BaseRepository {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }
  save(req, res) {
    //Ao fazer qualquer referência a this.model o erro é retornado.
    res.status(201).json({ pokemon: 'save' });
  }
}

export default BaseRepository;
```

Quando eu tento acessar o atributo model no arquivo BaseRepository é retornado Cannot read property 'model' of undefined, mas se eu der um console.log no this.model no constructor ele é exibido no terminal.
Gostaria de entender o por que do erro, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode estar também acontecendo um problema de bind, ou seja, quando uma função de outra lib passa a existir dentro da classe ela ainda sim possui o escopo próprio dela mesma, acontece muito em Javascript de você ter que usar o this porém o this da classe que vc construiu as vezes não é o this da função externa que você está usando porque pode ser ela ela tenha um this próprio.
Como resolver: 
você pode acrescentar uma arrow function ao invés de usar a função normal, pois a arrow function em ES6 é uma função sintética que trata essa questão do this:

```js
class BaseRepository {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }
  save = (req, res) => {
    //Ao fazer qualquer referência a this.model o erro é retornado.
    res.status(201).json({ pokemon: this.model });
  }
}

export default BaseRepository;
```

Ou se você preferir, e/ ou não tiver com os transpiladores de es6 no seu node você pode fazer um bind no seu construtor:

```js
class BaseRepository {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.save = this.save.bind(this)
  }
  save(req, res) {
    //Ao fazer qualquer referência a this.model o erro é retornado.
    res.status(201).json({ pokemon: this.model });
  }
}

export default BaseRepository;
```

Todas as duas formas de resolver também são válidas. :)

Comment: Utilizei a abordagem do bind e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Teria que fazer uns testes antes pra entender direito, mas você poder

```js
class Quadrado extends Poligono {
  constructor(comprimento) {
    // super chama o construtor da classe pai que vai atribuir comprimento para
    // os atributos comprimento e altura herdados pela nossa classe filha Quadrado  
    super(comprimento, comprimento);
    // Nas classes filhas, super() deve ser chamado antes de usar o this. Sem ele 
    // vai ocorrer um erro de referência. O this agora se refere a classe filha Quadrado
    this.nome = 'Quadrado';
  }

  // os atributos a seguir são herdados da classe pai Poligono: altura, comprimento e area.

  get area() {
    return this.altura * this.comprimento;
  }

  set area(valor) {
    this.area = valor;
  } 
}
```

Mas vale também dar uma conferida na assincronissidade dos dados, pra ver se o seu comando não está sendo executado antes dos dados chegarem para você. Da uma olhada aqui

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/classes-es6/index.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor